# Why is the text in my navbar overlapping?

Tags: html, css, nav, overlap

I have a rather nice navbar but unfortunatly, when I resize my laptop window a bit, the text starts overlapping. It seems to be stuck in the middle and wont make use of all the space, despite me having checked throughly that here are no padding or margins causing this.

[This is how it looks on a big screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qDjil.jpg)

[this is the problem when I narrow the window a bit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ejnil.jpg)

Could someone please help me figure out why this is happening, please?
I would be very grateful.

My main CSS navbar (displayed on small screens):

```
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*, *:before, *:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

/* I tilfælde af at der skal cleares */

br.tabula {
  clear: both;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: orange;
}

/*Fjerner underline osv.*/

a:link, a:visited {}

a:hover {}

a:active {}

/***********************************************************/

/*                     Specielle!                          */

/***********************************************************/

/***********************************************************/

/*         Billeder! Img!    ******      Video!            */

/***********************************************************/

#burger {
  width: 15px
}

img.lille-l {
  float: left;
  margin: 8px 20px 20px 0;
  width: 160px;
  height: 165px;
}

img.mellem-r {
  float: right;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 350px;
}

img.top {
  margin: 8px 0 20px 0;
}

.sponsor {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 0;
  padding-bottom: 22px;
}

.klik {
  padding: 5px;
  box-shadow: 3px 5px #888888;
}

#socialbar img {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
}

iframe {
  width: 390px;
  height: 250px;
  float: left;
  padding: 10px 15px 10px 0px;
  border: none;
}

/***********************************************************/

/*                       Tekst!                            */

/***********************************************************/

h1, h2, h3 {
  margin: 0 0 1% 0
}

/*****************************************************************************/

/*                   HEADER!       ******         BANNER!                     */

/******************************************************************************/

#bannerkat {
  margin-top: 1%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 46px;
  background-image: url("billeder/katte/mathilde.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  color: white;
  border-bottom: solid 1px #444444;
}

/******************************************************************************/
/*                               NAV!                                         */
/******************************************************************************/
/* Menu Button */
#menu-button {
   z-index: 1;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
  position: absolute;
  position: fixed;
  top: 15px;
  right: 5px;
  transition: all 0.2s ease;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 50px;
  height: 35px;
  background-color: #19c589;;
  border-radius: 5px;  /* pæne runde hjørner*/
-moz-border-radius: 5px;    /* Fox*/
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;    /* IE */
}

nav p {display:none;}
#mainlogo {display:none;}


#menu-button .bar {
  display: block;
  height: 4px;
  background: black;
  margin: 4px;
}

#menu-checkbox {
  display: none;
}

#menu-checkbox:checked ~ #menu-button {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}

nav ul {
    position: fixed;
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
    }

#menu-checkbox:checked ~ #menu {
  display: block;
}

#menu {
  display: none;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border-radius: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#menu li {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: beige;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 7px 2px 7px 2px;
}
```

*This is the code for the nav in the images, displayed on larger screens with media query:*

```css
    
#mainlogo {display: block;}
#bannerkat {display: none;}

  #menu-button {
    display: none;
  }
  #menu {
    display: block;
    border-radius: 0;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
  }

  .mainheader {width: 100%;    padding: 0 auto;
      margin: 0}
  #menu ul {width:100%;    padding: 0 auto;
      margin: 0}
  #menu li {
    display: inline-block;
      width: 12%;

    background: none;
    padding: 0 ;
    margin: 0;
  }
  #menu li a {
    font-size: normal;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #505050;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 75px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    transition: all .4s ease;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    border-top: 5px solid #80bb80;
  }
  #menu li:nth-of-type(2) a {
    border-top: 5px solid #9b5e5e;
  }
  #menu li:nth-of-type(3) a {
    border-top: 5px solid #5656b3;
  }
  #menu li:nth-of-type(4) a {
    border-top: 5px solid grey;
  }
  #menu li a:hover {
    border-top: 5px solid darkgreen;
  }
}

nav {  font-family: helvetica, arial, sans-serif;}

/* højde for billed-sektion*/
section {min-height: 204px;}

#baggrund {
 background:
url("billeder/katte/sophi.png");
 background-size: cover;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-attachment: fixed;}

   #mainlogo {
   font-size: 37px;
   color: white;
   border: 7px solid white;
   display: inline-block;
   padding: 10px;
   position: absolute;
   height: 123px;/* hvid boks*/
   line-height: 25px;
   top: 202px;
   margin-top: -180px;
   left: 50%;
   width: 600px;
   text-align: center;
   margin-left: -300px;
   text-shadow: 1px 2px 1px #000;
   box-shadow: 1px 2px 1px #000;  }
 /* og omegns */
 #mainlogo p {font-size: 20px; padding:5px;}

.vector{width: 60px;
margin-left: -450px;
margin-top: -36px;}

.mainheader {margin-top: 10px;}

/* Navigations menuen (links osv) */
#nav_wrap {
  background: #f9f4ea;
  width: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  float: left;
  height: auto;;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 144px;
  bottom: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 00;
  opacity: .9;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 4px beige;
  padding: 0;
}


/* MAIN! BODY! *********************************************************/

body {
  background-image: url("billeder/bgorange.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  color: black;
  /* Base font size (14px)? 7%*/
  font-family: sans-serif, arial;
  line-height: 1.5;
  text-align: left;
}

.body { width: 90%;}

.maincontent {
  line-height: 20px;
  width: 79%;
  float: left;
  border-radius: 5px;
  /* pæne runde hjørner*/
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  /* Fox*/
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  /* IE */
}
```

Comment: At a cursory glance I would guess it's because you have a width of 12% set on your menu's `li` elements, and at that screen width 12% is less than the width of the text, causing the text to spill out. There are workarounds but it depends how you want the text to behave - for the most flexibility it would be better to create the menu using flexbox.

Comment: Could you tell me a bit about how I would go about doing that?
I have tried using flexbox for nav before, but it made everything behave oddly, and I am a bit scared to ruin the nav bar I already have.

Comment: Remove width:12% and space-out the menu items with padding/margin. Use media query to widen the nav bar in narrow width(as per the image I can see spaces on left and right side of the nav bar)

Answer (score 0):

@Ginger
You should remove fixed width: 12% from #menu li.

Comment: I unfortunatly have to add a width, the CSS width for my smaller screens is #menu li 100% and that value "takes over" if I do not give my bigger nav a width of some sort.

Comment: Ah, I am so silly! You are right, I can use width: auto instead, and that works perfectly! Thank you Shiva and Cbroe. My inexperience seems to be showing in a rather embarrassing way, I mostly use auto for height and margin, so I did not even consider it for width.

Ehm, I am afraid I do not quite know the rules for this and I am terribly sorry to ask "a question within a question" as it is against the rules but do I use the checkmark next to Shiva´s answer even though the answer was in the comments?

Comment: @Ginger have them update the answer, then accept it.

Answer (score 0):

`#menu li` word needs to be wrapped and `font-size` should be small on lower screen size. i.e `word-wrap:break-word`